# activate/enable javascript plugins based on user options

Tags: javascript, web-services

I'm building a JS client for a set of REST WebServices. The client will be delivered as an embeddable iframe, which should load JS scripts based on user options (license profile, user admin options, etc.)

I wonder what's the most effective and efficient pattern to do that.
At now I have a single "bootstrap" script, which includes the other scripts. I could create  the bootstrap script code dynamically (server side), to make it load only the set of scripts required by the user configuration. Anyway those scripts would be publicly available, even if the services are not enabled for certain users... IMHO that's not a good solution.

On the other hand, how to control the access to static javascipt files on a public folder?
I want to avoid to serve javascript code though my code. It would be an expensive overload for the application!

Mmm... I'm a bit confused...

Giovanni

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you wish to control access to a resource based on a business requirement (licenses, user profiles etc) you have no choice but to route all requests for that resource through your application.

However, since you are you are sending the files to the client there is no guarantee that anyone in possession of the scripts is currently authorized or authenticated (license may have expired, etc). As such, you cannot infer that a request to your web services is valid based on the fact that a consumer knows how to call your web service.

There should be very little to lose in making the scripts publicly accessible (since there should be nothing that you wish to kept secret in them). So, in answer to your question, I would suggest authenticating and authorizing any requests at the web service level and allowing the javascript files to be publicly accessible.